# AWS Step Functions does not catch error when Lamba function returns an error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-step-functions

I have been struggling with AWS Step Functions for hours now. The use case is quite simple as I want to get gradually familiar with AWS Step Functions. However, I think I do not understand how they handle errors that come back from a failed lambda function.

[image: My State Machine]

Here is the corresponding code:

```json
{
  "Comment": "A simple AWS Step Functions for managing users with in the context of the AWS Training Initiative at AXA.",
  "StartAt": "Process-All-Deletion",
  "States": {
    "Process-All-Deletion": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "InputPath": "$",
      "ItemsPath": "$.Users",
      "MaxConcurrency": 0,
      "Iterator": {
        "StartAt": "DeleteAccessKeys",
        "States": {
          "DeleteAccessKeys": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:###:function:listUserAccessKeys",
            "Next": "DetachUserPolicy",
            "Catch": [
              {
                "ErrorEquals": ["NoSuchEntityException"],
                "ResultPath": "$.DeleteAccessKeysError",
                "Next": "CatchDeleteAccessKeysError"
              }
            ]
          },
          "DetachUserPolicy": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:###:function:detachUserPolicy",
            "Next": "DeleteIamUser",
            "Catch": [
              {
                "ErrorEquals": ["States.TaskFailed"],
                "ResultPath": "$.ErrorDescription",
                "Next": "CatchDeleteUserPolicyError"
              }
            ]
          },
          "DeleteIamUser": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:###:function:deleteIamUser",
            "End": true,
            "Catch": [
              {
                "ErrorEquals": ["States.TaskFailed"],
                "ResultPath": "$.ErrorDescription",
                "Next": "CatchDeleteIamUserError"
              }
            ]
          },
          "CatchDeleteIamUserError": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:###:function:errorHandler",
            "End": true
          },
          "CatchDeleteAccessKeysError": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:###:function:errorHandler",
            "Next": "DetachUserPolicy"
          },
          "CatchDeleteUserPolicyError": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:###:function:errorHandler",
            "Next": "DeleteIamUser"
          }
        }
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.Result",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

So basically the state machine should catch the error properly and the status should be orange respectively 'caught error' in 'DeleteAccessKeys'. Instead it turns into green.

This is the code of my lambda function:

```py
import boto3 
import botocore

print('Loading deleteUserAccessKeys function...')

def deleteUserAccessKeys(message, context):

    # Get IAM client
    client = boto3.client('iam')
    item = message['Name']

  
    try:
        # List all keys associated with the user
        result = client.list_access_keys(UserName=item)
        accessKeyIds = [accessKeyId for element['AccessKeyId'] in result['AccessKeyMetadata']]
        
        # Exit if there are no access keys
        if not accessKeyIds: return message
        
        # Delete all keys associated with the user
        for element in accessKeyIds:
            client.delete_access_key(
                UserName=item,
                AccessKeyId=element
            )
         
        message['DeletedAccessKeys']=len(accessKeyIds)
        
        print(message)
        return message

            
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as error:
        print(error.response)
        if error.response['Error']['Code'] == 'NoSuchEntity':
            print('Entity not found exception')
            raise error
        else:
            raise Exception("Failed! Check the error!")
```

What might be the issue or what did I wrongly configure?

Comment: It seems to me that it is caught correctly since its in  `Outputs`. Don't know why console shows its as green. Maybe some strange display bug?. More importantly, does your machine works as expected, regardless of what the console shows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason by myself.
I removed the the type "Map". I tried it then with just one single input without any iteration.

```json
{
  "Comment": "A simple AWS Step Functions for managing users with in the context of the AWS Training Initiative at AXA.",
  "StartAt": "DeleteAccessKeys",
  "States": {
    "DeleteAccessKeys": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "InputPath": "$.Users",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:####:function:listUserAccessKeys",
      "End": true,
      "Catch": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "NoSuchEntityException"
          ],
          "ResultPath": "$.DeleteAccessKeysError",
          "Next": "CatchDeleteAccessKeysError"
        }
      ]
    },
    "CatchDeleteAccessKeysError": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:####:function:errorHandler",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

In the Web GUI it is then correctly displayed as "Caught Error" if e.g. the entity (NoSuchEntityException) does not exist.

[image: Caught Error Example]

If you iterate over input values as in my example in my first post caught errors will always be displayed as "Succeeded".

Comment: Hi,
I am struggling too with AWS Step functions error handling. Is there a way to directly catch the ClientError? I am having a catch block that has "States.ALL" specified in "ErrorEquals".
The catch block and invokes an error handler function defined in a task state. However, the error passed to this handler is a dict and not of type "ClientError". Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to check the exact exception name returned from your lambda. Check lambda's log to confirm this.

In case you want to quickly check if thats the problem, change the catch attribute under `DeleteAccessKeys` to `States.All`. This is the superclass of all named exceptions.